# Problems installing PHP on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, php

I am trying to install PHP 7 on Windows Server 2008. I have the following in my httpd.conf

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
LoadModule php7_module "C:/Apache24/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPiniDir "C:/Apache24/php"
```

The problem I am having is a syntax error which says "The specified module could not be found" but the file php7apache2_4.dll exists. Not sure what I need to do now.

Comment: Well does it exist in that location? The installation path looks a bit strange. In addition you could check if it's blocked (file properties). If you extracted it using the built-in zip support that might be the case.

Comment: That is why it is curious to me, since it does exist in the folder but I'll try moving the folder

Comment: Did you check the DLL properties? How did you install PHP on that server? If it was the binary package did you extract it using the built in zip tool?

Comment: Yes but I can't see anything in properties to indicate it's locked

Comment: What happens if you try to execute the PHP executable in the PHP directory? Can you execute it? If not it's likely a problem with the installation.

Comment: The eecutable doesn't give any errors. I may just use IIS instead and use the web platform installer